# How do I use variable substitution in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Trying to emulate `compose` file type deployment via Service Fabric service manifest specifically for environment variables in the container. Static values work fine, what is not working/documented is how do I pass something from the host into the container. 
In compose following code will put `hostname` variable from container host into container environment variable, how do I do that in Service Fabric manifest?

```
 environment: 
  - "SHELL=powershell.exe"
  - "HostName=${hostname}"
```

Comment: did you try using an empty value? e.g. `- HostName`

Comment: You mean like ` <EnvironmentVariable Name="hostname" />` ? I want SF fabric to pass this information to container which runs inside service fabric, so values are entered in XML in applicationmanifest.xml

Comment: no, I mean 

`environment: 
  - SHELL=powershell.exe
  - HostName`

Comment: I don't do compose deployment to service fabric. I do traditional deployment based on `applicationmanifest.xml`. Code above is what compose file looks like if I would do deployment to `docker swarm`

Comment: It appears to be unsupported at this time: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/186

Comment: Thanks. Add this as answer to the question and I accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be [unsupported](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/186) at this time, according to the referenced github issue.